# SQL: как подсчитать количество значений в двух таблицах?

Tags: sql

Всем привет. У меня есть две таблицы, `question` и `field`. Мне нужно подсчитать количество записей в обеих таблицах, для которых значение поля `template_id` (присутствует в обеих таблицах) совпадает с искомым.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Объединить (UNION) и посчитать. Или посчитать отдельно (subq, CTE) и сложить.

Comment: можете описать пример ниже, чтобы я мог принять Ваш ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посчитайте в каждой и сложите результат

```
SELECT 
     (select count(*) from question where template_id = ...)
   + (select count(*) from field where ...) as cnt
```